# Swift: Get double value from 'index' in enumeration

Tags: ios, swift

In a simple Swift enumeration like this:

```
for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        let indexValue = idx as NSNumber
        let double = indexValue.doubleValue
        .... }
```

is there an easier way to convert the 'index' value to a double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
    let doubleVal = Double(index)
}
```

The number types in Swift generally have an init method that takes any of the other number types.